# Prestashop wrong payment automatically added to order

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am observing strange behavior:

Every new order has wrong payment in backoffice.

It doesn't matter what type of shipping or what type of payment I choose, every time one particular payment appears. Even if no payment was already made, or order status changed.

Error is shown on image bellow:

[image: The error is shown here:]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with module "Custom order reference" which wasn't auto - incrementing order reference for some unknown reason. I couldn't remove it from admin, so I had to delete it manually via ftp and remove overridden classes.

Now it is working.